# htaccess: how to block ip in a rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess

is it possible to block some ip or allow some ip

in some specific htaccess rewrite path

eg: using a php mvc framework, there is a htaccess to rewrite the query string(controller) into slash format, i want to allow some ip access on some specify controller without PHP code

is it possible to use htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

It is covered by the first section of the Apache Manual chapter on [Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html)

Comment: so it is impossible to use htaccess only!